# Terminate Failure Action Logic App Result is not showing in api Response

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

Terminate Failure Action has a parameter Message to give in the OutPut but I am not seeing that into API Response.

[image: Azure Logic App Result]

In the API Response, I am seeing "NoResponse" and some other message text

[image: API REsponse]

I want to get the same response in API as the Terminate Action in Azure Logic App.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reproducing from our end, we can able to make this work by adding a response action before terminate nad have the error message in the body of the response action. Below is my logic app flow.

[image]

**RESPONSE IN POSTMAN:**

[image]